# nivoslider ie8 jquery bug, cannot find it

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, nivo-slider

I have got a little problem in IE8 with the nivoslider script and i cant figure out what is wrong with it.

http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/

It works in all other browsers but IE8. Some help would really be appreciated.

Besides that it states a JS error on line 155 in the jquery js script. I think that has to do with the nivoslider since all other pages do not show this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from these lines in `/wp-content/themes/jobroller/includes/js/theme-scripts.js?ver=3.0`:

```
/* add jquery lazy load for images */
jQuery('img').lazyload({
    effect:'fadeIn',
    placeholder: '../../images/grey.gif'
});
```

Nicer error message from Firefox:

> jQuery("img").lazyload is not a
>   function

You are loading `jquery.lazyload.mini.js?ver=1.5.0` before that first script, but it's not working regardless.

---

**Update:**

Your "Nivo Slider HTML":

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    ..
    <a href="pakketten"><img src=".." alt="" />
</div>
```

You've forgotten to close the last `<a>`! This will work:

```
<a href="pakketten"><img src=".." alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: i gave you a +1 on the lazyload error.
Though the error on 155 is still there in IE8. and still nivoslider does not work properly.

Comment: It does kinda work, and the buttons flash up for a second and you can click them and it changes the image (so Nivo Slider is "working"). But then, the error you describe comes up. The error is coming from `http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/wp-content/themes/jobroller/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js`. Can you replace that with the exact same version of jQuery, but not minified? It's very, very annoying to debug problems with minified versions of scripts.

Comment: Done, error is now on line 6490. Thanks for the help sofar btw. Hopefully i can check this as the right answer in the end :)

Comment: Well, after backtracking through rather a lot of JavaScript, it turns out that it's a HTML error! I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: wow, that was soooo stupid of me! Thanks! I was convinced that it was a JS error. Ill mark as right answer :) Pretty ashamed though